# Passing uniform array to CSGL shader from gnome extension

Tags: gnome-shell-extensions

I have a CSGL shader that declares this uniform...

```
uniform float Targets[6];
```

I'm writing a gnome extension that attempts to set this with the following code in extension.js...

```
let fx = new Clutter.ShaderEffect(
    { shader_type: Clutter.ShaderType.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
);
var targets = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5];
fx.set_uniform_value('Targets', targets);
fx.set_shader_source(shader);
```

However, the call to set_uniform_value() is failing.  Is there a way to pass an array value to a CSGL shader from extension.js ?